# Get results when where value is 'grade' or where it doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, wordpress, left-join, key-value, buddypress

I have a wordpress site that is used to store student grades on various lessons (from the quizzes on the site). I am trying to create a query that will pull out all of the lessons for all students in a certain group (using buddypress groups) and the students grades in each lesson.

I have created this query:

```
SELECT u.display_name, p.post_title, cm.meta_value
FROM wp_users u
JOIN wp_bp_groups_members gm
    ON u.ID = gm.user_id
JOIN wp_comments c
    ON u.ID = c.user_id
JOIN wp_commentmeta cm
    ON c.comment_ID = cm.comment_id
JOIN (SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type LIKE 'lesson') p
    ON c.comment_post_id = p.ID
WHERE gm.group_id = 4 AND cm.meta_key LIKE 'grade'
```

This currently returns all the grades for all students in a group in the lessons they have attempted the test. However it does not return any lessons they have not attempted the test in, which I need still.

Just to be clear: lessons are posts, grades are meta_values in a record with a meta_key of 'grades'. These are stored as comments, and comment_meta.

I hope this is all clear and you can help. Thanks.

After Ollie Jones help I made this:

```
SELECT u.display_name, p.post_title, IFNULL(cm.meta_value,'--nothing--') grade
FROM wp_users u
JOIN wp_comments c
LEFT JOIN wp_commentmeta cm
    ON c.comment_ID = cm.comment_id AND cm.meta_key = 'grade'
JOIN wp_bp_groups_members gm
    ON u.ID = gm.user_id
JOIN wp_posts p
    ON c.comment_post_id = p.ID
WHERE gm.group_id = 4 AND p.post_type LIKE 'lesson'
```

Which almost works but returns all student grades, not just the ones in the group (though it only gives the one name of the student in the group).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the familiar key/value store problem, that comes up with `commentmeta`, `postsmeta`, and `usermeta`.  When you `JOIN` two tables and the left one might not have a corresponding row, you need to use `LEFT JOIN`. When the left one is a key/value table, you need to adjust the `ON` condition accordingly. Finally, when you `LEFT JOIN` two tables and there's no matching row in it it, you get back `NULLs` for those columns, so you must allow for that.

So this kind of SQL pattern will do the trick for you

```
SELECT whatever, IFNULL(cm.meta_value,'--nothing--') grade
  FROM whatever
  LEFT JOIN wp_comments c ON whatever.id = c.user_id
  LEFT JOIN wp_commentmeta cm ON c.comment_id = cm.comment_id
                             AND cm.meta_key = 'grade'
  JOIN whatever
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, it's definitely brought me closer. I've added an edit to my question as it has made one problem.

Comment: I'm marking this as correct as it led me to the answer. I had to left join both wp_comments and wp_commentmeta. Thanks you.

Comment: ah, thanks for figuring it out. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a user_id in your comments table? I dont see where you joined which user posted which comment. So when you join the group_members to the users table, you are specifying which users to show, but since you are not joining on user id when you join to your comments table, it will show all the comments for all the users. Im not sure if this will work for your table, but try:

```
SELECT u.display_name, p.post_title, IFNULL(cm.meta_value,'--nothing--') grade
FROM wp_users u
LEFT JOIN wp_comments c 
   JOIN wp_commentmeta cm
   ON c.comment_ID = cm.comment_id AND cm.meta_key = 'grade'
   JOIN wp_bp_groups_members gm
   ON c.user_ID = gm.user_id
ON u.user_id = c.user_id
JOIN wp_posts p
ON c.comment_post_id = p.ID
WHERE gm.group_id = 4 AND p.post_type LIKE 'lesson'
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: That brings us back to the original problem unfortunately of not showing the lessons where a student hasn't attempted the test.

Comment: Perhaps you need to left join to comments as well if that is where the user id is kept. I will edit my answer above.